# Grails flash scope acts differently with HTTPS

Tags: flash, grails, https

When I force HTTPS through Tomcat (or `grails run-app -https`), an object stored in flash that is otherwise not null turns out to be null. I've tested this on different environments and this is consistently the case.

In the below sample, `foo` is executed first and `foo.gsp` submits to `bar.gsp`

```
ControllerA {
  def foo = {
    flash.obj = myObj
  }

  def bar = {
    println flash.obj // is null
  }
}
```

Not sure if the flash scope should survive from the controller method `foo` to `bar` but then why does it work without SSL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: shot in the dark: flash more or less uses the session; is your request changing the http->https boundry and thus getting a new session due to the cookie beeing tagged as secure?

Comment: My understanding is that the flash scope would only survive from action `foo` to `bar` if the former redirects to the latter

Comment: @cfrick no http to https change as far as I know as https is enforced on a container level for the whole web app.

Comment: @dónal thanks for the insight. But really strange that this works with http. I'll try a different scope.